# File.ReadLines throws OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, file

I have a strange issue that I can't seem to find a solution for.
I'm trying to read large files (from 500Mb up to 2Gb) by chunks of 8M lines.

For that, I created the following:

```
public static List<string> read_file(string path, Int32 start, Int32 end, Boolean is_big_file)
{
    try
    {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        if (is_big_file)
            lines = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(start).Take(end - start).ToList();
        else
            lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();

        return lines;
    }
    catch { return null; }
}
```

If the file has less than 8M lines, ReadAllLines is used and everything works.
If the file is more than that, it will use ReadLines.Skip.Take.

The first chunk works, I receive the first 8 M lines.
start = 0. end = 8,000,000.

The second chunk doesn't work. 
start = 8,000,000. end = 16,000,000 or the last line of the file (depending on the number of lines). 
For some reason, I get OutOfMemoryException when I have less than 8M lines to read (end = 12,500,000).

Do you have any idea why it happens? Does Skip caches the original lines as well?
Is there a more elegant solution for it?

Thanks!

Comment: In each call reading any subsequent chunk you are physically reading all the previous lines (chunks) as well. No wonder it eats memory like crazy. You should better work with the file using a StreamReader.

Comment: May I ask, How does the caller invoke this method, for a large file, to read multiple batches? What is surprising to me is, while your approach may be **extremely in-efficient**, File.ReadLines returns an IEnumerable, which internally uses StreamReader (same as the accepted answer below), to read one line at a time... Unless you are explicitly holding large number of lines in memory, or doing something else wrong, it should be hard to get OOM exception (not impossible though.. and again, the approach is certainly in-efficient).

Comment: If you are implementing batching of lines only due to concern that you have a large file to process, and all you need to do is process every line once, one line at a time, I'd recommend that you keep it simple, and just use the `IEnumerable` returned by the `ReadLines` method to iterate over all lines.. All lines should not be loaded, given how the Iterator is implemented using `StreamReader` (No need to re-invent the wheel, if I understand your need correctly). See - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,d989485a49fbbfd2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, using this:

```
File.ReadLines(path)
```

You are reading **ALL** lines. You better use a `FileStream` and `Seek` to the bytes you want to read. Something like this:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
{
    fs.Seek(start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(fs);

    string line = tr.ReadLine();
}
```